# which iso file to download in order to upgrade rhel from 7.2 to 7.6

Tags: centos, redhat-enterprise-linux, yum, rpm

we have 762 linux rhel servers with version 7.2

we want to upgrade all servers to rhel 7.6 but off-line ( without network )

from redhat site - https://access.redhat.com/downloads/content/69/ver=/rhel---7/7.6/x86_64/product-software

we see many ISO types , but not sure which is the right iso in order to upgrade the  rhel machines

[image]

Comment: It appears to be the Binary DVD, but since Red Hat's *raison d'être* is *service*, contact them for support.

Comment: but why not just download the ISO ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Boot image` is small. Just enough to boot and then download everything you need for the installation from the internet.
The `Guest Image` is a small image of working RHEL in a virtual machine.

That you need is `Binary DVD` and maybe `Supplementary Binary DVD`. It depends on the package set you have installed.

What you need to do with these images is described in https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1355683